# Android TTS not working in device

Tags: android, text-to-speech

The TextToSpeech like in

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html

works fine on the Emulator but does not work on my device (galaxy s).. is there anything extra that I need to install?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What language are you using? If your device doesn't have the language installed, it, obviously, can't play it. If it's anything but US, try that. If so then please post your code.

Comment: Then ya I would check and verify your (target) device(s) have the requisite language packages. I thought English was default though... Can you post you code, see for sure it isn't a code problem?

Comment: Thank you for  ur response.. I tested in another device and worked fine. It was my phone..

Answer (score 3):

On my Captivate, I had to manually install (prompted by Google Navigation) the TTS data files to enable speech directions. This may have been because the rom didn't include them.  I can't recall if the stock rom had the speech files or not.  See this link for how to detect the presence of the right files:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html
Basically

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

and check the result (should be CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)

Answer (score 1):

On Samsung device go to Settings -> Language -> text to Speech and select Google TTS instead of default Samsung engine.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem with my samsung GT-S7392, here's the solution if text to speech is working on emulator but not on your phone. Just go to the settings, and set the language setting to US or UK, then run your app. It will work fine.