# Android Studio Text to Speech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I wrote a program which converts a given text into speech.
My code works perfectly on the emulator, but I couldn't achieve the same result on my device.
Can you help me, showing me where is my problem?

MainActivity.java

```
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.util.Locale;


 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     TextToSpeech ttsobject;
     int result;
     EditText et;
     String text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ttsobject = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new      TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
             @Override
             public void onInit(int status) {
                 if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                     result = ttsobject.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            } else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Feature Not      Support Your Device ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

     }

     public void doSomething(View v){
         switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bspeak:
            if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO SUPPORT FOR LANGUAGE ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
            else{
                text = et.getText().toString();
                ttsobject.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bstopspeaking:
            if(ttsobject!=null){
                ttsobject.stop();
            }

            break;
     }
 }
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(ttsobject!=null){
        ttsobject.stop();
        ttsobject.shutdown();
         }
     }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Speak"
    android:id="@+id/bspeak"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bstopspeaking"
    android:onClick="doSomething"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STOP"
    android:id="@+id/bstopspeaking"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bspeak"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:onClick="doSomething"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bspeak"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp" />
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680248/android-tts-not-working-in-device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680248/android-tts-not-working-in-device) check it may help you

Comment: i think you have to do some settings in your android device ......http://www.greenbot.com/article/2105862/how-to-get-started-with-google-text-to-speech.html

Comment: Thank you but It doesn't work... Is there any other way that you know?

Comment: Setting the 3rd parameter as `null` in `speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null)` can sometimes cause problems. Follow a TTS example and use a hashmap (or bundle if new API) and set the utterance id.

Comment: I tried the application on a different phone that android version is under 6 and it works perfectly. I didn't understand the version problem.