# Android TTS speaks only on emulator, not on a real device

Tags: android, text-to-speech

If I start the app on an emulator and press the button I can hear the sound, but if it runs on the real device I don't hear any sound (volume level is ca. 80%):

```
...
        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    Log.d("TTS", "ok");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TTS", "error");
                }
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t1.speak("What is your name?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });
...
```

According to the output in LogCat everything is fine, but I cannot hear any sound if I press the button:

```
I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
TTS: ok
```

What can be the problem? Emulator API Level is 4.2.2, device - 4.2.1.

```
root@android:/ # ls /system/tts/lang_pico/                                     
de-DE_gl0_sg.bin
de-DE_ta.bin
en-GB_kh0_sg.bin
en-GB_ta.bin
en-US_lh0_sg.bin
en-US_ta.bin
es-ES_ta.bin
es-ES_zl0_sg.bin
fr-FR_nk0_sg.bin
fr-FR_ta.bin
it-IT_cm0_sg.bin
it-IT_ta.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If your device doesn't have the language installed or doesn't support, it, obviously, can't play it. If it's anything but US, try that...!

[does this helped?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986998/7012517)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I changed the language to US. It didn't help. The link that was suggested by someone to check whether languages are installed on the device doesn't work anymore. And I have no other device to check.